# Friendly fork of contributions from library X to library Y with a different but similar license

Tags: mit-license, apache-license, forking

If there's a large contribution to a library X licensed under [Apache v2.0](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) from user A and user A decides to create a "friendly" fork of the contributions he/she made in library X to a new library Y licensed under [MIT license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License).

Both Apache v2.0 and MIT are commerical permissive license. But would that be legally okay?

Are there guidelines or best practices on such scenarios of "friendly" fork?

Answer (score 2):

First off many Open Source libraries & frameworks contain components that are licenced under different, compatible, licences - *some actually contain components under incompatible licences*.

There are a couple of points that you need to address:

- Is **all** of the code that you are planning to fork **your** work **only**, *with no contributions from others*? - If others have contributed while the code is under one licence you really need to consult with them before changing the licence on the parts that they have contributed to, also note that extensive consultation with others that resulted in you changing your code is still a contribution from them.
- You *should*, morally *even if not necessarily a legal requirement*, at least discuss the proposed move with the maintainers of library X - they may wish to make library Y an external dependency or to carry on maintenance of the existing code under the original licence.
- Your new code should include in the documentation files references and URLs for the original project and mention the original licence.

*Please note that I am a developer **not** a legal expert!*